# How to flag records using a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server, and I am trying to flag duplicate records using a CTE.

Duplicate records are selected based on having the same Call_GUID, Call_Type_ID, and Date.

I am using the ROW_NUMBER function to categorize the duplicate records.  I want to flag all duplicate records except for the first record written based on the "DateTime" column.

The initial data looks like this:

| DateTime | Call_Type_ID | Call_GUID | Dup_Flag1 | DupRank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-21 09:28:01.370 | 12986 | 00A4AB00000100000000520883048B0A | NULL | 1 |
| 2023-09-21 09:35:08.270 | 12986 | 00A4AB00000100000000520883048B0A | NULL | 2 |
| 2023-09-21 09:35:29.887 | 12986 | 00A4AB00000100000000520883048B0A | NULL | 3 |

The expected result should be this:

| DateTime | Call_Type_ID | Call_GUID | Dup_Flag1 | DupRank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-21 09:28:01.370 | 12986 | 00A4AB00000100000000520883048B0A | NULL | 1 |
| 2023-09-21 09:35:08.270 | 12986 | 00A4AB00000100000000520883048B0A | Y | 2 |
| 2023-09-21 09:35:29.887 | 12986 | 00A4AB00000100000000520883048B0A | Y | 3 |

Instead, I am getting this:

| DateTime | Call_Type_ID | Call_GUID | Dup_Flag1 | DupRank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-21 09:28:01.370 | 12986 | 00A4AB00000100000000520883048B0A | Y | 1 |
| 2023-09-21 09:35:08.270 | 12986 | 00A4AB00000100000000520883048B0A | Y | 2 |
| 2023-09-21 09:35:29.887 | 12986 | 00A4AB00000100000000520883048B0A | Y | 3 |

I am using the query below, but the "WHERE d.DupRank > 1" condition is not being applied.

I am also getting an error message when trying to put an alias (Dups) on the subquery.

```sql
WITH Dups AS
    (SELECT 
    "DateTime",
    Call_Type_ID,
    Call_GUID,
    Dup_Flag1,
    DupRank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER
        (PARTITION BY Call_GUID, Call_Type_ID, "Date" ORDER BY "DateTime" ASC)
    FROM #temp_records_SLS_U65_ALL
    WHERE Call_GUID = '00A4AB00000100000000520883048B0A') 

UPDATE #temp_records_SLS_U65_ALL
SET Dup_Flag1 = 'Y'
FROM #temp_records_SLS_U65_ALL AS t
INNER JOIN Dups AS d
ON t.Call_GUID = d.Call_GUID
WHERE d.DupRank > 1;
```

Comment: FYI, the preview section is there for a reason; to enable you to preview the post prior to submitting it and make sure it looks correct. Please do make sure you check this first; you'd have noticed your post was quite malformed.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Why would you remove those markdown tables I put in for images..!?

Comment: Error message when adding this "WHERE Call_GUID = '00A4AB00000100000000520883048B0A') AS Dups"
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: You don't alias a CTE in the CTE declaration. You give it a name after the `with` as you did. If you want to alias it, you do so in the statement where it is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include something to make your join more specific. You're only joining your temp table to the `dups` table on `Call_GUID`. You need to be joining on *at least* all the fields you're using in your `partition by` clause.

Even so, in your example, that's not sufficient.

```
drop table if exists #table
create table #table
(
    Dt datetime,
    CallTypeId int,
    CallGuid varchar(50),
    DupFlag char(1)
)

insert into #Table
values
('2023-09-21 09:28:01.370', 12986, '00A4AB00000100000000520883048B0A',  NULL),
('2023-09-21 09:35:08.270', 12986, '00A4AB00000100000000520883048B0A',  NULL),
('2023-09-21 09:35:29.887', 12986, '00A4AB00000100000000520883048B0A',  NULL)
```

Consider, this is the query you're essentially running to do your update:

```
;with dups as
(

    select 
        Dt,
        CallTypeId,
        CallGuid,
        DupFlag,
        DupRank = row_number() over (partition by CallGuid, CallTypeId order by DT)
    from #table
)
select *
from #Table t
inner join dups d
    on t.CallGuid = d.CallGuid
        --and t.CallTypeId = d.CallTypeID
        --and t.Dt = d.Dt
where d.DupRank > 1
```

Notice you get six rows, when you started off with three. What you're doing here is applying a value of "Y" to _every row with a `CallTypeId` of 12986 and a `CallGuid` of 00A4AB00000100000000520883048B0A. That's.. everything.

You need to add additional fields in there (again, at least the other partition column(s) and in your case, *also* the datetime field)

```
;with dups as
(

    select 
        Dt,
        CallTypeId,
        CallGuid,
        DupFlag,
        DupRank = row_number() over (partition by CallGuid, CallTypeId order by DT)
    from #table
)
select *
from #Table t
inner join dups d
    on t.CallGuid = d.CallGuid
        and t.CallTypeId = d.CallTypeID
        and t.Dt = d.Dt
where d.DupRank > 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Xedni and Thom A.  Both solutions work. Thank you for your advice as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a running `COUNT` here and if the value is `1` it's the first row, if not, it's a duplicate:

```sql
SELECT [DateTime],
       Call_Type_ID,
       Call_GUID,
       CASE COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY CONVERT(date,datetime),Call_Type_ID,Call_GUID ORDER BY Datetime
                           ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) WHEN 1 THEN NULL ELSE 'Y' END AS DupFlag
FROM (VALUES('2023-09-21 09:28:01.370','12986','00A4AB00000100000000520883048B0A','NULL','1'),
            ('2023-09-21 09:35:08.270','12986','00A4AB00000100000000520883048B0A','NULL','2'),
            ('2023-09-21 09:35:29.887','12986','00A4AB00000100000000520883048B0A','NULL','3'))V(DateTime,Call_Type_ID,Call_GUID,Dup_Flag1,DupRank);
```

As an `UPDATE` with would look like the following:

```sql
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT [DateTime],
           Call_Type_ID,
           Call_GUID,
           Dup_Flag1
           CASE COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY CONVERT(date,datetime),Call_Type_ID,Call_GUID ORDER BY Datetime
                               ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) WHEN 1 THEN NULL ELSE 'Y' END AS DupFlag
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
UPDATE CTE
SET Dup_Flag1 = DupFlag;
```